# Add HTML attr via PHP

Tags: php, html, jquery, forms

First page has form using method POST with action to the offer page.

```
<form id="value-form" method="POST" action="/offer/">
```

When user submits form on the first page, I want on the offer page `class="add-info"` to be added to the `<form` so then it fires up the jQuery script

```
<form id="formOffer" class="add-info">
```

**Jquery**

```
if (formOffer.hasClass('add-info')) {
        launchrocket(); 
    }
```

I can't figure out class tag can be added via PHP to the new form on the process page.

Comment: Set a hidden form field and give it a value. eg; 1. Since you are using POST, in your 2nd page, retrieve value and use if statement to say if its 1, then add your class.

Comment: `<form id="<?php echo (isset($_POST)) ? 'add-info' :  'formOffer'; ?>" class="add-info">` if the user submits the post request it will add `class = 'add-info'` else `formOffer`

Comment: Thank you @RohitSahu appreciate your help. I've used your approach and it worked, I've slightly edited it, but anyways thanks.

Comment: @Gosi yeah I've also thought of doing the same by adding hidden field, thank you for your suggestion